# Random element generator

Tags: javascript

I have 6 background images of dice numbers and want to select one at random. It works, but at random returns the error ‘in dice[diceRandom] (), ‘dice[diceRandom]’ is undefined. Could somebody help me -pointing out where I can learn it is fine, I’m not after free help. Cheers, Gareth.

```js
let dice = [function six() {
    document.getElementById("dicediv").style.background =
      "url('dicesprite.png') 0, 0";
  },
  function five() {
    document.getElementById("dicediv").style.background =
      "url('dicesprite.png') -50px , 0";
  },
  /* .......... */
  function one() {
    document.getElementById("dicediv").style.background = "url('dicesprite.png') -100px , 0";
  }
];

let diceRandom = Math.round(Math.random() * dice.length);
dice[diceRandom]();
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="dicediv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Missing </script> </body> are just typos

Comment: `floor` instead `round`.

Comment: Yep, with `length = 3` and `random() = 0.9`, you get `2.7` which `round`-ed gives you `3`. Index `3` corresponds to the *fourth* element and there isn't such.

Comment: Thanks. That’s done it. Very grateful.

Comment: Thanks all and thanks for the explanation, VLAZ. Helpful and I’ll read/ learn on. Question can now be deleted.